# Trying to make a js class for html (Changing background image every few seconds), need a helping hand

Tags: javascript, html, class

Hello i am trying to make a class to have numerous object changing background images on a site without creating each object one by one.

So i have done this to change the background image of one "object" :

```
let x = 0; //index

const image = ["assets/img1.jpeg", "assets/img2.jpeg", "assets/img3.jpeg"]; //images to show

function displayNextImage() {
    x = (x === 2) ? 0 : x + 1;
    document.getElementById("myID").setAttribute("style", "background-image: url(" + image[x] + ")") //change images 
};

function startTimer() {
    setInterval(displayNextImage, 3000); //start looping
}

startTimer();
```

It work and so i want to make it a class :

```
class changingImageObject {
    constructor(img1, img2, img3, id) {
        this.image = [img1, img2, img3];
        this.id = id;
        this.x = 0;
    };

    displayNextImage() { //Change the showed image x+1
        this.x = (this.x === 2) ? 0 : this.x + 1;
        document.getElementById(this.id).setAttribute("style", "background-image: url(" + this.image[this.x] + ")");
    };

    startTimer() { //Change image after 3sec (looping)
        setInterval(this.displayNextImage, 3000);
    };
}

const changingImages = new changingImageObject("assets/img1.jpeg", "assets/img2.jpeg", "assets/img3.jpeg", "myID");
changingImages.startTimer();
```

I added the script at the end of the html, it create the object but the displayNextImage function give a error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of null
at displayNextImage

Thx for reading

Comment: What do you get when you console.log `document.getElementById(this.id)`?

Comment: Oh, its null, and when i do console.log(this.id) in displayNextImage its undefined, i dont understand why tho... And when i do console.log(this.id) in the constructor i got the id...

Comment: After setInterval all the variable in my object become undefined...

Comment: I see. It seems you need to [bind the `this` value to the function](https://javascript.info/bind). Try adding `this.displayNextImage.bind(this)` to your constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems i needed to bind my method to the constructor, thanks to Mubaraq.

Code with correction.

```
constructor(img1, img2, img3, id) {
        this.image = [img1, img2, img3];
        this.id = id;
        this.x = 0;
        this.displayNextImage = this.displayNextImage.bind(this);
    };
```

Now i need to learn the use of bind :)